# Angular ComponentFactory.resolveComponentFactory(Component) Param as String

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I need an app with drag drop func where components are injected into each other using ComponentFactoryResolver. 
Problem here is i have created a injectable event handler class which is like a shared service class responsible for creating factory and inject it into the target. Now i need to pass the (ColumnComponent) ref

**Method Available :**

```
injectComponentToTarget(sourceComponentClassName : string,targetComponentRef : any) : boolean {
 let factory = 
 targetComponentRef._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Colu
 mnComponent);  //Need to use sourceComponentClassName
 /** rest of code for insertion **/
}
```

as string

**Method Expected :**

```
injectComponentToTarget(sourceComponentClassName : string,targetComponentRef : any) : boolean {
 let factory = 
 targetComponentRef._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(sourceComponentClassName); 
 /** rest of code for insertion **/
}
```

As for the official Docs there is no help. I am stuck here !
Way i tried is created another file and tried exporting all Component Class Name and then

```
import * as ComponentClass from ../lib;
```

and the lib.ts

`import from =
export * from 'row.component';
export * from 'column.component';`

but it doesn't compile in CLI saying cannot find Module 'component/lib'

Comment: Please post the exact error message in addition to "doesn't compile".

Comment: it says cannot find Module 'components/lib'......

Comment: That doesn't look like the exact error message, at most a part of it

Comment: ive made the edit to the question with some more details plz check